# Cannot scroll in upward direction

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, appium

I am using

```
    action = TouchAction(self.driver)
    action.press(self.element).perform()
    height = self.element.size["height"]
    action.move_to(x=0, y=height*int(height_multiplier)).perform()
```

to scroll in android.But if i give height_multiplier as `1` or `2` it works fine.Scroll downward too.But when i give it `-1` or `-2` expecting it too go upwards it gives an error

```
The coordinates provided to an interactions operation are invalid.
```

I have already tried `scroll(element1,element2)` but it doesnt scroll ,just flicks to end.also `driver.execute` doesnt work as well as `mobile:scroll` is not yet implemented for android.Does anybody know a workaround?Partial scroll is what i want precisely

Comment: i hope the element you are trying to do it is not the topmost element on the screen, in which case the coordinates using `-` (negative) multiplier will not be in the screen

Comment: From the java documentation : 
  " Move current touch to a new position relative to the current position on
  * the screen. If the current position of this TouchAction is (xOld, yOld),
  * then this method will move the TouchAction to (xOld + x, yOld + y).
  * param x change in x coordinate to move through
  * param y change in y coordinate to move through
  * return this TouchAction, for chaining
  */"

Comment: @nullpointer didnt get ur first point........even if it the first element ... -ve value realtive to it should be somewhere down right?

Comment: nopes...top left corner of your screen is (0,0) and bottom right be (x,y) varying according to the screen resolution...so now i hope you understand my point. eg 10+ (-2*6) is not feasible

Comment: @nullpointer it should be realtive but i could see in appium logs it was not relative and absolute....dont know if its a bug ina ppoium

Comment: it would be great if you could share the logs with the question as well :) could be a bug, cannot comment over that

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented scrolling up as follows: `driver.swipe(0, scrollStart, 0, scrollEnd, 2000)` where `scrollStart < scrollEnd`. Both values still must be positive to fit in the resolution range.